# Typedef of templated class inside class

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I'm wondering why the following code works:

```
template <class T>
class A {
  public:
  typedef A* Pointer;
  typedef A<T>* OtherPointer;
};

int main()
{
  A<double> a;
  A<double>::Pointer b = &a;
  A<double>::OtherPointer c = &a;
  std::cout << b << " " << c << std::endl;
}
```

The syntax for `OtherPointer` looks logical to me. I'm wondering about the one for `Pointer`. Is the name of the class implicitly the templated type inside the class definition? If so, why does the other syntax work as well?

Comment: `A` and `A<T>` are both interchangeable within the scope of `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works because inside the class template `A<T>`, the type name `A` is an alias for the fully-described type `A<T>`. Your template definition above is equivalent to:

```
template <class T>
class A {
  public:
  typedef A<T>* Pointer;
  typedef A<T>* OtherPointer;
};
```

As you can see when you write it this way, `A<T>::Pointer` and `A<T>::OtherPointer` are `typedef`s for the same type (which is just `A<T>` itself). Therefore, your example compiles successfully.

Someone else may be able to quote from the relevant portion of the standard on this. It should be said that I know that this is an area in particular where I've seen bugs in some older compilers in the past, where `A` is not treated as equivalent to `A<T>` inside the template definition.

Comment: [temp.local]/p3 : *The injected-class-name of a class template or class template specialization can be used either as a template name
or a type-name wherever it is in scope.*

Comment: @PiotrS.: Thanks; you have impressive speed.